# Ansible | comando inválido

Tags: shell, ansible, yaml, yml

estoy intentando crear una tarea dentro de un rol para hacer logout de la sesión, pero a pesar de que lo he intentado de diferentes formas, al ejecutar "ansible-playbook logout.yml host", me da error > `ERROR! 'shell' is not a valid attribute for a Play`

Este es el fichero .yml, gracias por adelantado.

```
---
- name: Logout Session
  shell: pkill -KILL -u $USER
```

Comment: No sé nada de ansible, pero me parece que puedes 1) Revisar la identación correcta, 2) Tal vez lo que nencesitas antes es la clave "tasks".
Eso lo leí en esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246837/ansible-playbook-error-command-is-not-a-valid-attribute-for-a-play

Comment: Hola, no me ha servido. @Cuauhtli